# Categories with basepoints from forgetful functor

Tags: category-theory

The example of the forgetful functor:
$$U: \text{Vect}_K \rightarrow Set$$
mapping the category of vector spaces over field $K$ to Set yields the category of elements consisting of based vector spaces $(V,v)$ for some $v \in V$; i.e. $\int U \cong V_*$. We then see that $(K,1)$ is initial for this category of elements (and so is any one-dimensional vector space with fixed base vector).

Does this construction apply more generally? That is, do all categories with basepoints arise from the category of elements of a forgetful functor applied to the original categories?

Answer (score 0):

Given a category $\mathcal C$ with a terminal object $1$, you can *always* define the category of pointed objects of $\mathcal C$ as the coslice category $1 \mathop \backslash \mathcal C$

- whose objects are the morphism $x \colon 1 \to X$ for any object $X$ in $\mathcal C$,
- whose morphisms $x \to y$ are those $f \colon X \to Y$ in $\mathcal C$ such that $fx=y$.

If $\mathcal C$ is well-pointed, it really is what you want to call the category of  pointed objects.

Now, if you consider $\hom_{\mathcal C}(1,-) \colon \mathcal C \to \mathsf{Set}$ to be *forgetful* (it actually is faithful in the well-pointed case), then of course you have a pretty straightforward isomorphism
$$ 1 \mathop \backslash \mathcal C \simeq \int \hom_{\mathcal C}(1,-) $$